# Webkit Wrapper for Desktop Apps

Tags: webkit, wrapper, desktop

I have a desktop app based on HTML/JS that needs WebKit to function at a reasonable speed. Normally, I would live with IE behaving badly, but its JS engine is just too slow.

I would normally go to Appcelerator for this, but it seems they have discontinued their desktop SDK and left it for the "community"...

This needs to function on Windows PCs, or I would just use Fluid (http://fluidapp.com)...

Is there a simple Webkit wrapper that I can use, or should I build one really quick in something like Qt. I haven't used Qt in a while, so I'd have to look at it again and make sure WebKit is implemented in it...

Answer (score 3):

While it is somewhat node.js-oriented, [AppJS](https://github.com/appjs/appjs) may offer what you're looking for. If it doesn't already support other scripting languages, it might at least provide a good example to start from.

**Update**: in the time that's passed since my original answer, it seems [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) fills a similar role but has gathered and maintained more momentum than AppJS. It's a little more focused, in that it doesn't attempt to provide much additional "framework" on top of simply exposing the node.js API to the window's JS context.

There's also https://github.com/atom/atom-shell, which I just learned of and may be similar.

One other thing to note is that (presumably with either, but at least with node-webkit), you **MUST** be cautious of any [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)-like vulnerability in your app that an attacker could exploit to gain complete access to the user's native machine. So if you are simply needing to package an offline web app in a downloadable desktop distribution, you may wish to research more PhoneGap-like solutions (e.g. [Mac OS X as PhoneGap platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017811/mac-os-x-as-phonegap-platform)) or a plain web view wrapper (like mentioned in the OP) that do not expose an entire OS-level native API — as node.js does — into the JavaScript environment.