# Mac OS X as PhoneGap platform

Tags: macos, web-applications, cordova, native, porting

I have phonegap app and I wish to port it to Mac OS X

Is there any similar to phonegap platform that make it possible to build native apps for Mac OS X from web apps.

I also interested in Windows and Linux.
I wish to be able to hide app in tray and create dialog windows.

**UPDATE**

I selected Cordova/PhoneGap that now support Mac OS X. When I asked question PhoneGap had no support on desktop but think change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I expermented with MacGap which was a port of Phonegap to OSX. https://github.com/maccman/macgap

You are a little limited in features.

Comment: Thank You. Is it similar to iOS where you have direct access to ObjectiveC and Plugins ?

Answer (score 3):

For writing HTML/Javascript applications that run on OSX, you always have the choice of writing a Chrome packaged app: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html

Interestingly, with the news recently that Chrome packaged apps can be run through Cordova and deployed as iOS and Android apps, Chrome packaged apps now can deploy both mobile and desktop: http://blog.chromium.org/2014/01/run-chrome-apps-on-mobile-using-apache.html

Comment: Really interesting. I need tray icon on Mac OS X. So I selected Cordova/PhoneGap that now support Mac OS X

Answer (score 3):

The best alternative I've found so far is **NodeWebkit**:
https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit

You can develop cross platform desktop apps with HTML5, Javsacript and CSS.

You also have the power of **NodeJS** to perform everything that a regular browser does not allow you to do.

A Very nice template is available for you through Yeoman:
https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-node-webkit

---

Another alternative is **Brackets Shell**: https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell

It is the foundation of a code editor sponsored by Adobe, but I tend to like more the first option.

Hope it helps!